# AJAX form submission confirmation message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I've got some jQuery code I've been working with from phpacademy on YouTube (I'm a total noob with js and jquery by the way!) that submits a form via AJAX - that all works fine.

My question is, on the AJAX success callback function I want to be able to refresh the page THEN show the confirmation div (the page is a list of users with an add new user form at the bottom).

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're refreshing the page, why bother with an AJAX request?

Comment: The whole point of AJAX is not to refresh the page - I would question the rationale

Comment: For Beginners, Read SO FAQ's

Comment: The only reason I was refreshing was to refresh the list of users to add the new one submitted by the form. Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refresh the div which is displaying your Users List as follows:

Return the new Users List from your server and the build your list in form of table or list in jquery and display it in div.

Fo eg:

```
<div id="result" />

$.ajax({
     url: "test.html",
     ....
     }).done(function(result) { // Here result will contain the list which you will have to return from the server side
          ..// Your Code to Loop through the result and prepare the list and append it to div.
           // For eg:
           $.each(result, function(key,item) {
               $("#result").append("<li>" + item.propertyName + </li>);   // Append list to div
           });
     });
```